# Titan : How to check the index characteristics, such as UNIQUE or not?

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan, rexster

I am using TITAN 0.4 version, with cassandra as storage backend. There are certain indexes created on Vertex properties. I want to check whether they are `UNIQUE()` or not?
Since I am using `0.4` version, `g.getManagementSystem()` is not available.
I am able to list the Indexes using `g.getIndexedKeys(Vertex.class)`.
But details such as uniqueness is not mentioned.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

The ManagementSystem API made this kind of work much easier than it used to be in 0.4.x and prior of Titan.  `g.getIndexedKeys` is a Blueprints method and doesn't give you very much as you have found.  You should explore these methods: [TitanGraph.getType](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/0.4.4/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanGraph.html#getType(java.lang.String)) and [TitanGraph.getTypes](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/0.4.4/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanGraph.html#getTypes(java.lang.Class)).